# maven bundle plugin build error

Tags: apache-flex, osgi

When I run `mvn clean install`, maven throws the following exception:

> Exporting packages that are not on the Bundle-Classpath[Jar:dot]

I could build successfully a few days ago, why is it happenning?

Comment: Since answering this I see that the original question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32458371/osgi-bundle-compile-error) has much more information. It would be helpful not to ask the same question twice with radically different amounts of information in it!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be certain without details of your POM configuration, but it looks like you're using a bnd based plugin, which probably means the `maven-bundle-plugin` or the `bnd-maven-plugin`.

In either case the bundle that's being produced is exporting a package which is not in the bundle. This is a sure-fire way to break your application, and so bnd is failing the bundle creation.

At a guess (because I don't have much information to go on) one of the following has happened:

- Somebody has renamed a package in your bundle but not updated the export in the pom file
- Somebody has removed a dependency from your pom that was previously being pulled into your bundle as a statically linked dependency
- Somebody refactored a SNAPSHOT that you were using and it no longer contains the package you wanted to export
- Somebody has embedded a jar file into your bundle, but not added it to the bundle classpath.
- It is also possible (but less likely) that someone has configured your classes not to go into the root of the bundle archive, so classes are not relative to `.`.

Fixing the first three issues is easy, either fix the package name, re-add the right dependency, or remove the export. The last two are also fairly easy to fix. You can change your bundle classpath like this:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: /path/to/my.jar, /path/to/another.jar, /path/to/folder
```

Another, probably better, option is not to include the code in a nested JAR file, but instead to embed the code directly in your bundle. This would mean adjusting your plugin configuration to use embedding syntax. As I don't know what plugin you're using I can't give you an example, but the documentation for bnd's include resource is [here](http://bnd.bndtools.org/heads/include_resource.html)